# Is there a way to paginate firebase data without a snapshot?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase collection called activity with 4 documents inside, with timestamps of 2, 3, 4, and 5 o'clock.

When I query it like so

```
let postsQuery = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`activity`)
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .limit(2);
```

I correctly get the 5 and 4 o'clock posts.

However, when I call the function again with the following conditional:

```
// oldest post is the 4 o'clock document
if (oldestPost) {
      postsQuery = postsQuery.startAfter(oldestPost);
    }
```

I get the 4 and 5 documents again.  If I change startAFter to be any other filter, I get 0 documents returned.

So my question is, am I just doing it wrong, OR can I not pass in a document.data() as the filter, and i need to pass in the original document instead?

Comment: Apparently, not calling .data() on the document, and using it as oldest post worked.  yay!

Comment: Pardon, but... I'm kinda curious if you solved your own question and also the bit of code where you used to call `.data()`, would you kindly update your question with the original `.data()` code so that we may understand the context behind your comment? And, y'know, if you could also post it in an answer and mark it as accepted that would help other people facing similar problems. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So answering my own questions:
when i got my posts, I was just storing them in an idMap

```
postsQuery
.get()
.then((documents) => {
    const typeIdToDocument = {};
    documents.forEach((document) => {
        const data = document.data();
        typeIdToDocument[document.id] = { id: document.id, ...data };
    });
```

Then when I passed in an startAfter, I used the .data() result of the post.
However, it worked when-
A) I passed in the original firebase document, not the .data() version
OR B) I passed in the Firebase Timestamp, rather than the full document

```
postsQuery = postsQuery.startAfter(oldestFirebaseTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two overloads of [`startAfter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#startafter):

1. `startAfter ( snapshot :  DocumentSnapshot < any > )`, which is the one I recommend you use whenever you can
2. `startAfter ( ... fieldValues :  any [] )`, into which you can pass just the field values of the document to start after.

The reason I recommend the first overload is that there may be cases where you have multiple documents with the same field value. The first overload is smart enough in that case to use the document ID to disambiguate between those and not return any overlapping documents. The second overload can't guarantee that.